# Create a permalink to a pdf?

Tags: redirect, rewrite-rules, media, pdf

I have a website where I want the permalink to my resume to be [www.example.com/resume](http://www.example.com/resume), so that whenever I send someone that link, it goes to the most recent version of my resume. But I don't want my resume to be a webpage -- I just want the permalink to send people to a PDF file, say http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Resume-v4.pdf. This way people with the [www.xyz.com/resume](http://www.xyz.com/resume) link always see the most recent version, regardless of when I sent it.

If possible, I'd also like to be able to redirect people who have the link http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Resume-v4.pdf to be redirected to [www.xyz.com/resume](http://www.xyz.com/resume), and then sent to the newest version of the file.

I've tried using a few plugins for this, but nothing seems to be able to generate permalinks for media files. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the first part using the [Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/). Just set the Request URL to **/resume** and the Destination URL to **/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Resume-v4.pdf**

For the second part of your question, you can add a redirect rule to your .htaccess file:

**Redirect /wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Resume-old.pdf /resume**

The way you worded your question you actually would set up an infinite redirect, so I changed it here to "Resume-old.pdf".

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly.